Use libgcc/compiler-rt altrenative with GCC/Clang
I am writing small low-level runtime library for fun.
According to the libgcc website, low-level runtime library are libraries that compilers generates calls to its routines whenever it needs to perform some operation that is too complicated to emit inline code for. GCC uses this library automatically. Clang uses compiler-rt.
You can use -nostdlib, but that only disables libgcc, I want to use a different (my) library. With clang, I only found out how to use libgcc instead of LLVM's compiler-rt.
How to tell GCC or Clang to use my own library instead of libgcc or compiler-rt?

Background have a read of Freestanding and hosted implementations

hi You can use -nostdlib, but that only disables libgcc, I want to use different (my) library what else is there to "disable"? So use your library, do you receive any errors? I do not understand - why -nostdlib is not a solution? There are also other -no* switches, did you research them? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

There is no question in your post. You should always write a post of a Stack Overflow question to ask a clear specific question. If you are asking how to use your own library instead of the GNU C standard library, then, besides —nostdlib, you can simply list your library in the command line to link a program, after any other modules that may need it.

I am not writing normal C library which I would link using -l. libgcc is library which compiler uses to perform some operations when it needs to. Looking through link options, I don't see how to tell to GCC to use other library which libgcc altrenative.

@Andrej: One reasonable option is to just name your own library libgcc. Obviously, you can't ship it under that name, but it can help you to get started.

Linking works the same way for libraries specified with -l as it does for those specified by naming them in full or other ways. If you use gcc or clang to build, those commands invoke the linker with a list of libraries. You can see those by using the -v switch, which will cause them to show the link command they use. Using -nostdlib and listing your own library instead is a fine way of substituting your own library. If you do not want to do that, you would either need to install your library in a default path that gcc or clang uses or rebuild them with different defaults.

Note that the defaults will be different on different systems. E.g., Apple builds clang differently than you may find it built on a Linux system. So configuring gcc or clang to use your library may be different on different systems.

@EricPostpischil This is not library which program uses, this is library which compiler uses.

@Andrej: So you mean it is a library the compiler uses in its own execution, during compile time, not a library it uses in linking. The title and the body of your post say “runtime library,” which commonly refers to the run time of a program built by the development tools. You should edit them for clarity. The page you link to is not about a library GCC calls during its execution. It is about a library GCC generates calls to, meaning it puts calls to the library routines in the code it is generating for the program being compiled.

Yes. GCC generates calls to this library when it's compiling code. I explained this what libgcc does in question. I didn't really know what to put in title, GNU call it low level runtime library. I'll rephrase to something more clear.

The command gcc -nostdlib -lyour_lib should work since GCC still uses the calls to the function, and you basically just overwrite their implementation.

Thanks a lot. Turns out I just have to disable libgcc and compile this library as any normal library.

If you are prepared to compile a custom version of GCC, I have a solution.
If you are new to this, I recommend you read OS Specific Toolchain as it provides a good background on this topic.
GCC allows you to define LIBGCC_SPEC in the config files during this process. As described in gcc/gcc.cc,

config.h can define LIBGCC_SPEC to override how and when libgcc.a is
included.

This would allow you to utilize a custom libgcc equivalent directly without having to mess around with -nostdlib.

Thanks a lot for this answer. If I don't find how to tell GCC to use libgcc altrenative with already compiled GCC, I will try this method.
